# How to set start page in windows 8.1 app programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am developing an app that a page with information is only shown during the first time the app is opened. How can I go about making this possible?  I'm thinking of changing the Start Page programmatically, but how would I do this?

The project is just a Windows 8.1 Metro App, not a phone app, only on the Computer or Tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Local Settings:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings

Create a Boolean variable like 'isFirstTime' and initialize it to true. Only show the intro page if this value is true, and once you show it, set it to false so the user never sees it again.